# Solving a system of equations involving smooth functions

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde

I have asked the following question in math.stackexchange, but I could not receive the answer. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063463/solving-a-system-of-equations-involving-smooth-functions).

Suppose $h_{i\overline{j}}$, where $1\leq i, j\leq n$, are functions defined on $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $h_{i\overline{j}}$ are smooth when viewed as functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$
and $H=(h_{i\overline{j}})$ is a Hermitian positive definite matrix. I wonder if it is always possible to find smooth functions $p_1,..., p_n$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ such that 
$$\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial z_j}+\overline{\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial z_i}}=h_{i\overline{j}}\mbox{ and }
\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial \overline{z}_j}
-\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial \overline{z}_i}=0.$$
In a related question, I require $p_i$ to be holomorphic, which seems to be too strong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a possible way to solve it, assuming some properties of polynomials which I will state in the end: 
Write
$p_j(z)=a_j+\sqrt{-1}b_j$ for $1\leq j\leq n$. Equating the real and imaginary parts,
we see that solving $(1)$ is equivalent to solving
$$\tag{2}
\frac{\partial a_j}{\partial x_i}+\frac{\partial b_j}{\partial y_i}
+\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_j}+\frac{\partial b_i}{\partial y_j}=2h_{i\overline{j}},\\
\frac{\partial b_j}{\partial x_i}-\frac{\partial a_j}{\partial y_i}
-\frac{\partial b_i}{\partial x_j}+\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial y_j}=0,\\
\frac{\partial a_j}{\partial x_i}+\frac{\partial b_j}{\partial y_i}
-\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_j}-\frac{\partial b_i}{\partial y_j}=0
$$
where $1\leq i, j\leq n$.
Note that $(2)$ is a system of linear PDEs with constant coefficients. Let
\begin{equation}
P_{ij}^{k}(X_1,X_2,...,X_{2n-1},X_{2n})=\left\{
                                            \begin{array}{ll}
                                              X_{2j-1}, & \hbox{ if $k=2i-1$;} \\
                                              X_{2j}, & \hbox{ if $k=2i$;}\\
                                              X_{2i-1}, & \hbox{ if $k=2j-1$;} \\
                                              X_{2i}, & \hbox{ if $k=2j$;}\\
                                              0, & \hbox{ otherwise.}
                                            \end{array}
                                          \right.
\end{equation}
and
$$(u_1,u_2,...,u_{2n-1},u_{2n})=(a_1,b_1,...,a_n,b_n).$$
Then
the system of equations in the first line of $(2)$ can be written as
$$\sum_{1\leq k\leq l\leq n}P_{ij}^{k}\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1},...,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n},\frac{\partial}{\partial y_n}\Big)u_k=0$$
where $1\leq i\leq j\leq n$.

I guess that if $\{Q_{i,j}\}_{1\leq i\leq j\leq n}$ are polynomials
in $X_1$, $X_2$,..., $X_{2n-1}$, $X_{2n}$ such that
$$
\sum_{1\leq i\leq j\leq n}Q_{i,j}P_{ij}^k=0\mbox{ for all }1\leq k\leq 2n,
$$
then we must $Q_{i,j}=0$ for all $1\leq i\leq j\leq n$, which I have posted it as a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2086279/still-another-fact-about-polynomials).
If this is true, we can then apply Theorem 7.6.13 in the book of Hormander [
An introduction to complex analysis in several variables, Third edition, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1990]
to conclude that the system $(2)$ is solvable.